# Combing two dataframes in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine two dataframes

I would like to combine both the dataframes such a way that the accts are the same.

For eg, acct 10 should values in CME and NISSAN while the rest are zeros.

Comment: `df2.combine_first(df1)` how this works?

Comment: It's easier if you format with print(df.to_string()), that way DataFrames can be easily read via `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: What would be your expected output dataframe though?

Comment: @anky_91 please add urs an answer

Comment: ```df1.set_index('acct').combine_first(df2.set_index('acct')).reset_index()``` This should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

> > It will update null elements with value in the same location in other.

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Also, you can try:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('acct'),df2.set_index('acct')],axis=1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is merge these two DataFrames.

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the two. Since you want to match on the `acct` column, set the `on` keyword arg to `"acct"` and set `how` to `"inner"` to keep only those rows that appear in both DataFrames.

For example:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on="acct")
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| acct |       GOODM        |       KIS        |      NISSAN       |    CME    |        HKEX        |        OSE        |        SGX         |
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|   10 |                    |                  | 1397464.227495019 | 1728005.0 |                0.0 |                   |                    |
|   30 | 30569.300965712766 | 4299649.75104102 |                   |    6237.0 |                    |                   |                    |
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

If you want to fill empty values with zeroes, you can use `df.fillna(0)`.