# Concatenate Pandas dataframe preferentially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 similar dataframes (`df1` & `df2`), having the columns id,date,count.

I want to concatenate these 2 df's, in a way such that if the `{id,date}` overlaps, I want to give preference to the row from df2.

e.g.:
df1 has the record: `id1, 2018/02/03, 45`

df2 has the record: `id1, 2018/02/03, 65`

When I merge/concat, I only need the record from df2 i.e. {`id1, 2018/02/03, 65`}.

Apart from this duplicate resolve logic, I need all the other rows from both the df's as is. How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional arguments to the `drop_duplicates` functionality for this.

As a toy example, consider the frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id" : [1,2,3,4], "time" : [25, 35, 45, 15]})  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id" : [4,5,2,9], "time" : [19, 14, 11, 12]})
```

Then, all you need to do is concatenate `df1` and `df2`, and drop duplicates by `id` and keep the `last` to make sure the information is kept from `df2`.

```
df_concatenated = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset="id", keep="last")   

df_concatenated  
>  id  time
    1    25
    3    45
    4    19
    5    14
    2    11
    9    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `set_index` method and then loop to remove all encounters of `df2` items in `df1`.

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3], 'date' : ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], 'count': [11, 22, 33]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,5], 'date' : ['d1', 'd5', 'd6'], 'count': [44, 55, 66]})
 df1 = df1.set_index(['id', 'date'])
 df2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'date'])

 for index, row in df2.iterrows():
     if index in df1.index:
         df1 = df1.drop(index)
 print(df1.append(df2))

         count
id date
2  d2       22
3  d3       33
1  d1       44
2  d5       55
5  d6       66
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759347/combing-two-dataframes-in-pandas-python#comment96299704_54759347)

Per anky_91's answer, you should get the desired results with `df2.combine_first(df1)`

Check out the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for a detailed explanation on the behavior of this function when you combine 2 irregular dataframes.